# How to pivot and concatenate the index with columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do the following dataframe transformation, hope you can help me.

I have one dataframe that it is indexed by week,

```
       Name  revenue cost margin
week1  jon     10      4   6
week2  jon     11      3   8
week1  mary    15     10   5
week2  mary     6      8  -2
....    ...     ..     ..  ..
```

how could I, by the column name, to pivot that index and concatenate with the columns, creating index * len(columns)

To get the following result?

```
       Name  revenue_week1 cost_week1 margin_week1 revenue_week2 cost_week2 margin_week2
       jon          10         4            6             11         3            8
       mary         15         10           5              6         8           -2
      ....         ...         ..           ..             ..        ..           ..
```

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's unstack:

```
df=df.set_index('Name',append=True).unstack(0)
df.columns=[f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in df.columns]
df=df.reset_index()
```

output:

```
       Name     revenue_week1   revenue_week2   cost_week1  cost_week2  margin_week1    margin_week2
0       jon     10                  11              4           3           6               8
1       mary    15                  6               10          8           5              -2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and you help. Even though both solution works, I finally choose this one as the correct one, because I find it more intuitive. I have to say that the order of the weeks matter in my solution, but I was able to sort the columns after

Answer (score 2):

You can also `reset_index` and `pivot`:

```
df2 = df.reset_index().pivot(index='Name', columns='index')
df2.columns = ['%s_%s' % (a,b) for a,b in df2.columns]
df2
```

output:

```
      revenue_week1  revenue_week2  cost_week1  cost_week2  margin_week1  margin_week2
Name                                                                                  
jon              10             11           4           3             6             8
mary             15              6          10           8             5            -2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and you help. As I said a choose the other correct but both seems to do the work. I left the discussion open, so if there is enough arguments to change my mind, I can change it. Again, thank you

Comment: Well, both are very similar, if you're happy with @AnuragDabas's answer, just stick with it. It is good ;)